# WP7 Emulator not starting app

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I am making a game in XNA 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010 using Windows Phone 7.1

For some reason, whenever I hit F5 or the Run button, the emulator starts the app but immediately closes stops the app. I don't even get to see the actual game screen. It just transitions in to the game and then straight back out.

I don't have any build errors and I have the mode set to Debug.

I'm completely out of ideas. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

(Yes I have tried closing and re-opening both VS and the emulator - sadly to no avail).

**EDIT**

I found where it's falling over, It's messing up on these lines:

```
 TimeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;               
 if (TimeSinceLastFrame > MillisecondsPerFrame)
 {
     TimeSinceLastFrame = 0;
     FrameIndex++;
     if (FrameIndex > 5)
     {
        FrameIndex = 0;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you're doing is causing a runtime exception. Unfortunately, WP7/8 has very bad exception handling/messages so you will need to dig into this manually. Try commenting out your initialization code bit-by-bit till you figure out which part is causing the crash. Also look through the output in the output window to get a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: I've found the code where it seems to fall over on. If I remove it, it runs. Check my Edit please.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, silly me. It's all my fault. I accidently forgot to give a default value to my MillisecondsPerFrame property, that's all.